# How to check then display the result of two tables and check is exist or not-exist?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Tabel_A
---------
id  name
1   Kursi
2   Roda
3   Gigi

Tabel_B
---------
id  id_tabel_A
1   2

Result
--------
name    Status
Kursi   0
Roda    1
Gigi    0
```

Query of the Result : …………………… ?

Comment: Hint:use left join

Answer (score 2):

use `left join` and `case when`

```
 select name, case when b.id_tabel_A is null then 0 else 1 end as status
 from tableA a left join tableB b on a.id=b.id_tabel_A
```

Answer (score 0):

You apply  IF  syntax

```
 SELECT a.name, 
    IF(
        (
            SELECT count(b.id_tabel_A)
            from Tabel_B as b
            WHERE b.id_tabel_A = a.id -- connect
        ) > 0
     , "YES", "NO")  as status
 from Tabel_A as a
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `exists`:

```
select a.name, 
       (exists (select 1
                from tableB b 
                where a.id = b.id_tabel_A
               )
       ) as status
from tableA a;
```

The reason I prefer `exists` is that it automatically handles duplicates in `tableB`.  You don't have to worry about the query returning duplicate results.